# Array strings come out as undefined

Tags: javascript, html

So i've got an array of 9 strings, predefined, and when i try to call them out in a function they come out as undefined, i don't really know what am i doing wrong :/

```
function checkAns(){
    var nr_pytania = (document.getElementById("q_id").value)-1;
    var odpowiedz = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    var odpowiedzi = ["Mazury", "Korfanty", "Paderewski", "Wersalski", "Zaolzie", "Orlęta", "Wisła", "Haller", "Gdańsk"];

        console.log(odpowiedzi[0].charAt[0]);
        if(odpowiedz == odpowiedzi[nr_pytania])
        {
            document.getElementById("answer").value = "POPRAWNE!";
                for(var i=0; i<odpowiedzi[nr_pytania].length; i++)
                {
                    document.getElementById("letter"+nr_pytania+i).innerHTML = odpowiedzi[nr_pytania].charAt[i];
                }
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("answer").value = "Odpowiedź błędna!";
        }
```

}

So, the part that is the most important to me is:

```
    var odpowiedzi = ["Mazury", "Korfanty", "Paderewski", "Wersalski", "Zaolzie", "Orlęta", "Wisła", "Haller", "Gdańsk"];

    console.log(odpowiedzi[0].charAt[0]);
```

Because the console returns undefined, and im not really sure why :(

Comment: Should be `String.charAt(0)` instead of `String.charAt[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var odpowiedzi = ["Mazury", "Korfanty", "Paderewski", "Wersalski", "Zaolzie", "Orlęta", "Wisła", "Haller", "Gdańsk"];

console.log(odpowiedzi[0].charAt(0));
```

You need to change it from `charAt[0]` to `charAt(0)`.

[Additional reading for String.prototype.charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use **odpowiedzi[0][0]** - no need to use **charAt()** :)